# Just trying to clean it up (java)

Tags: java

```
// The "Ch_1_Summative" class.

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    c = new Console (40,60);
    c.setTextColor(Color.red);
    c.println(             "Baker Bob's");
    c.setTextColor(Color.black);
    c.println(         "73 Little Bridge St.");
    c.println("           Almonte, Ont.");
    c.println("               K0A 1A0");
    c.println("(613) 256-7674");
    c.println("____________________________________");
    c.println("");
    c.println("              ITEMS");
    c.print("2 Muffins                  $");
    c.println(2*1.25,1,2);
    c.println("Chicken Simosa             $1.60");
    c.println("Coupon #: 3265");
    c.println("Coupon Value: -25%");
    c.print("New Price                  $");
    c.println(.75*1.60,1,2);
    c.println("Dipping sauce              $0.50");
    c.print("3 Squares                  $");
    c.println(3*1.40,2,2);
    c.println("White Choclate Cookies     $4.75");
    c.println("Baguette                   $3.50");
    c.println("");
    c.print("Sub-total:                 $");
    c.println(2.50+1.20+.50+4.20+4.75+3.50);
    c.setTextColor(Color.blue);
    c.print("HST:                       $");
    c.println(.13*16.65,4,2);
    c.setTextColor(Color.black);
    c.println("____________________________________");
    c.setTextColor(Color.red);
    c.print("TOTAL:                     $");
    c.println(1.13*16.65,4,2);
    c.setTextColor(Color.black);
    c.println("");
    c.println("____________________________________");
    c.println("           PAYMENT");
    c.println("Type:                MASTERCARD");
    c.println("Card Number:        153-596-231");
    c.println("Verified by:                Pin");
    c.println("____________________________________");
    c.println("Date: Feb. 9, 2015");
    c.println("Receipt #: 3293071437");
    c.println("Cashier: Jacob");
```

I'm a complete noob to programming (as in been doing it for three days) and when this is run on the "Ready to Program" application it creates a receipt for a fake restaurant. I showed it to my teacher and he said that it was "messy code", is there any way to clean it up, keep it simple, but have the same product? ny help would be awesome!!!

Comment: This is a better question for codereview.stackexchange.com. Also, you should probably ask your teacher for some suggestions on how to clean it up.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your teacher means that instead of just having a bunch of string outputs, you should build this more like a general-use program. for example, you could make an `items` class, which would contain every item and its price and quantity, and if any coupons are available. Then, you could make an array of items and have the program go through the array and output all of the items and their prices. The program should also calculate the total using this array and, for an added bonus, generate random values for everything else (receipt #, etc).

Comment: If I was looking to create an items class, how would i go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

While AndrewlsOffline has a good point, I think those concepts might be a little advanced for this program (looks like it is Chpt 1, and the poster says he's been programming for 3 days). I'm thinking that your teacher meant group the code in a better way - all of those print statements one right after the other is difficult to read. Instead of

```
c.setTextColor(Color.red);
c.println(             "Baker Bob's");
c.setTextColor(Color.black);
c.println(         "73 Little Bridge St.");
c.println("           Almonte, Ont.");
c.println("               K0A 1A0");
c.println("(613) 256-7674");
c.println("____________________________________");
c.println("");
c.println("              ITEMS");
```

You could do

```
c.setTextColor(Color.red);
c.println(             "Baker Bob's");

c.setTextColor(Color.black);
c.println(         "73 Little Bridge St.");
c.println("           Almonte, Ont.");
c.println("               K0A 1A0");
c.println("(613) 256-7674");
c.println("____________________________________");

c.println("");
c.println("              ITEMS");
```

Grouping logical chunks together makes it easier to read. Of course, you could always ask your teacher what he meant by it like forgivenson said.